# "Abandoned" questions [unanswered/answered/abandoned]

Tags: feature-request

Serverfault should require to state explicitly that no answer has been accepted (e.g. after every 2 weeks for OPEN questions).

I have seen a few cases in which answers that seem correct have not been accepted by asking person. It is hard to tell if something was missing in the question or the question has been "abandoned".

Answer (score 3):

We used to have a feature here that helped with that, the accept-percentage below each questioner's user-badge. They went away about a month ago since they were causing more harm than good; people were refusing to answer questions from askers with low percentages and that's not what we're about.

Such a notifier does exist for brand new users. When they upvote an answer on their question, there is a popup that suggests that if its good enough, click Accept. Not all askers even bother to upvote though.

And finally, we have a dual feedback system here. Askers can Accept answers, and the rest of us vote for the one *we* think fits best. Sometimes these are two very different things; as a Moderator I occasionally get a flag worded like:

> The accepted answer is wrong, completely wrong. It should be unaccepted.

Which I can't do a thing about. Only one person can Accept an answer.

Don't look to the Accepted flag as your sole source of truth.

Comment: I have been looking at the issue from the perspective of published tags' unanswered percentages.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip the "unanswered" logic should consider questions with upvoted answers as answered questions (the same way the unanswered link does) -- If it doesn't I would consider that to be a bug (i.e. "Check for a post about it on [mSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and if none exists, raise the issue")

Comment: I'm rather miffed about the percentage thing being removed. I was one of those people who refused to answer when the OP had an exceptionally low percent.

Comment: @voretaq7 I do not think it should be a single rubber bag unless there will be a new category of questions: "answered"="up-voted or accepted answer" and "answer accepted (by asking person)".

Comment: The 'unanswered' stat being discussed here is the one at the top of the 'top users' page for tags. Like this one for [php](http://serverfault.com/tags/php/topusers) (21.8% unanswered) and [linux](http://serverfault.com/tags/linux/topusers) (11.6% unanswered). For comparison, right now our [site-wide unanswered rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) is 17%. Of the high traffic sites, we're actually doing pretty good.

Comment: @ChrisS, there can certainly be questioners who ask hard questions, which will rarely garner lots of answers (let alone acceptable ones). Punish them for that? This site is for _questions and answers_, if the question is interesting, and you believe you can give a good answer, please _do_ go ahead. If the asker is ungrateful, its their own loss.